# Spring MVC 3, JQuery .ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, spring

I am using JQuery ajax in Spring MVC 3.  When making the following call, I am running into a dilemma with myurl.  On the local development machine, myurl would be localhost:8080/myapp/my_json_controller.  On the production, my url would be domain/my_json_controller.  I tried using relative url, /my_json_controller, and it would not work on the development machine because of the /myapp part.  Any suggestion on how to make this work on both production and development?  Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
     url: myurl,
     data: mydata,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'get',
     cache: false,
     success: function ()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea include '/myapp' in your application source code. You should be able to access your controller only writing its name.

Have you tried using, in your JSP, `<c:url ...>` [tag](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html)? It can help you hiding your application base URL.

Comment: What if I need to use that function in a external javascript file? I couldn't use the <c:url...> tag...What to do??

Comment: @VitorBraga: You have a couple of options. You could generate the script file dynamically with JSP. But my favourite one is including some variables in a Javascript block in generated HTML. I usually put there the base path, language, date format, etc.